# Error while creating event reciever in SharePoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, error, event-receivers

I am working on creating the event receiver in SharePoint 2010.  When I create a new--> project--> event receiver, I choose the sandbox solution and hit ok.

I am getting the following error

> "Cannot connect to the SharePoint site: http://servername/. Make sure
>   that this is a valid URL and the SharePoint site is running on the
>   local computer. If you moved this project to a new computer or if the
>   URL of the SharePoint site has changed since you created the project,
>   update the Site URL property of the project."

I get this error all the time when I create any SharePoint solution and deploy it.  So usually I will just go inside the proj folder and change this 'projname.csproj.user' file's  tag `<SharePointSiteUrl>http://servername/</SharePointSiteUrl>` to `<SharePointSiteUrl>http://sitename/</SharePointSiteUrl>` and from then on it works fine.

But this time for event receiver, I'm getting that error and when I look into the project folder its empty.  I'm not sure how to work around this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure that when your go new -> project -> event receiver , then paste in your url for debugging http://site.com/sitetest/Home.aspx delete the "Home.aspx" or what ever it may be named,  so it ends up as "http://site.com/sitetest/"... also, I'm sure that you have SharePoint installed on the machine, but make sure your permissions are correct.

Comment: I'm also getting this error message.  What do "correct permissions" entail?  And why does the error message say that sharepoint should be running on the local machine if I'm trying to add an event receiver on a different server?

Comment: When developing in visual studio you must have sharepoint installed on that machine. So, for example we have a dev environment, and a production environment. Both environments are on two different computers. I remote into the dev environment and do all my visual studio work there. Then we deploy that into the production environment. For permissions you will need admin rights to the SharePoint server, dev computer, and site. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Click on your project name in Solution Explorer window.

[image]

Then, select *View -> Properties Window* from the main menu.

[image]

Finally, change **Site URL** property:

[image]

Comment: and, of course, make sure that the site under `http://servername` exists